# Рендер LaTex в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex

Добрый день! Есть ли библиотека для третьего питона, позволяющая преобразовывать Latex-код в png-картинку? Есть связка Sympy+Matplotlib, но это костыль. Там остаются видны оси, очень плохо с размерами шрифта и самой картинки, и тд.

Мне нужно, чтобы я в процессе обработки мог скормить ей список полсотни LaTex-строк и получить на выходе полсотни картинок.

Comment: вы хотите на чистом Питоне реализацию latex найти? (для небольших подмножеств могут быть готовый модули). В противном случае, можно просто из Питона соответствующие команды вызвать, используя subprocess модуль.

Comment: У меня tex-live стоит, так что модуль общающийся с ним тоже устроит. Я сварщик не настоящий,  так что про многие возможности просто не знаю. Subprocess гляну, спасибо.

Comment: для примера, это может выглядеть как: `check_call(['latex2png', filename], stdout=logfile, stderr=STDOUT)`. Вот [пример, как несколько команд одновременно запустить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279)

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел более простое решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. На случай если кто-то еще будет искать.

```
import sympy

sympy.preview(r'$$\frac{5}{a^{2}}$$', viewer='file', filename='test.png')
```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что `sympy.preview` использует `subprocess.check_output(['latex',...])` внутри (вывод команды накапливается в памяти и в случае ошибки показывается).